# Nested Control + Top, Left properties

Tags: silverlight

I have a silverlight control c1 that contains another silverlight control c2.
When trying to execute the below code.

```
c1.c2.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)
c1.c2.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty)
```

The result is always 0.
How can i get the Top and Left property for the inner control relative to the main canvas.

Comment: If I understand you correctly then c1 is a child of some Canvas, yes?

Comment: yes right, c1 is added on the canvas.

Comment: Can you show more context and how `c1` and `c2` are added to the canvas.

Comment: c2 is a shild of c1. The way I add them to the canvas is  this.Canvas1.Children.Add(c1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
var transform = c2.TransformToVisual(c1);
var relativePoint = transform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
var c2left = c1.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty) + relativePoint.X
var c2top = c1.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty) + relativePoint.Y
```

Comment: +1, although I would use `c2.TransformToVisual(c1.Parent)` and not bother with the expressions of the last two lines.